# Conclusions about a convergent nonnegative series

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Suppose we have a series of nonnegative real numbers such that the series is finite, i.e. convergent.

Does this imply that for any positive epsilon, there exists a positive integer N such that for all k > N the sum from k to infinity is less than epsilon?

I want to use this fact but I have only conjured it from intuition and so am somewhat reserved about it.

Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: This follows immediately from the fact that the partial sums converge to the limit. The "tail" is the difference between the limit and the partial sum and must therefore tend to $0$.